# Setup Task scheduler to restart OneDrive (Win 10)

Tags: windows, windows-10, sync, onedrive

I have a OneDrive installation with my library at  E:{20676961}\OneDrive - jp410\ I have updated the registry to reflect this location and it works. The problem is that this PC is the main server and it is not usually manned but I log into it frequently. For some reason, onedrive stops working and comes out with a "OneDrive requires reconfiguration" or "close" option. Whichever option I chose, onedrive is going to close by signing me out.

**Here is where it gets frustrating and I need help**. When I want to sign in, I have to reenter the the library location again because it defaults to the user/onedrive location instead of the E:{20676961... location.

I have reinstalled onedrive, reinstalled windows (2ce) and I am now looking for ideas as to how to automate the restarting option. I have looked at task scheduler but it seems that when onedrive stops, it does not generate an event so I can't use an event to resign in.

Even though the library location is in the registry, onedrive does not seem to refer to that. Is there any tool I can deploy that will sign me in to onedrive when it closes? Or is there a way I can create a task to automatically sign me out and sign me back in say every 2 hours? I am a tenant so I don't have the admin access to both Office 356 and onedrive for business.

Comment: Yes I did that during installation. I also did the registry fix. I will attempt the symbolic link and report back. Thanks

Comment: I have created the symlink and it works. Thanks. One final question because the site I googled did not explain it - when onedrive crashes and I sign on, I should leave the default C\Users\seanb\"Onedrive - jp410" location and just go with the flow? It will not start creating files at C:\Users\sean\... ; Or even if it did, all files will still be created at E:\{20676961}\OneDrive - jp410 which means C:\Users\seanb\OneDrive - jp410 and E:\{20676961}\OneDrive - jp410 are now one and the same?  Sorry my brain works in an ocd manner. I have to know the gritty details.  Many thanks.

Comment: Question: Will this symlink work when I access the PC remotely?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Retain different OneDrive folder save location

> **One way to handle this this would be to . . .**
>
> 1. Change the default location where you need it to save one time manually.
> 2. Then delete the default [OneDrive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OneDrive) folder and recreate
>      that as a [symbolic link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_link)
>      instead pointing to `E:\{20676961}\OneDrive - jp410` as the target using [mklink](https://ss64.com/nt/mklink.html).

With this configuration even if it defaults back the **symlink** points to the "E" drive location you need it to save files to. With a **symlink** wherever the "target" points to is where data is saved folder location wise when you save to the **symlink** so this sounds like exactly what you need.

So delete the **OneDrive** default folder and then run:

```
mklink /d "C:\Users\<UserName>\OneDrive" "E:\{20676961}\OneDrive - jp410"
```

**Note:** *When you access this PC (even remotely) as the user profile which you normally use, it will keep saving to the "E" drive folder location you need it to even if the software changes the location back to the default location since that is now a **symlink** pointing to the "E" drive folder location.*

---

### Further Resources

- [MKLink](https://ss64.com/nt/mklink.html)
- **`mklink /?`**

  > ```
  > Creates a symbolic link.
  >
  > MKLINK [[/D] | [/H] | [/J]] Link Target
  >
  >         /D      Creates a directory symbolic link.  Default is a file
  >                 symbolic link.
  >         /H      Creates a hard link instead of a symbolic link.
  >         /J      Creates a Directory Junction.
  >         Link    Specifies the new symbolic link name.
  >         Target  Specifies the path (relative or absolute) that the new link
  >                 refers to.
  > ```
- [Files save to OneDrive by default in Windows 10](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/files-save-to-onedrive-by-default-in-windows-10-33da0077-770c-4bda-b61e-8c8e8ca70ac7)

Comment: I need to test this a bit more but I have not had any popup error messages since Saturday evening when I put this into practise. I hope it works. I will watch and report  back as there is a lot of similar problems all over the net. Perhaps this may bea solution.

Comment: It has only stopped about twice since compared to almost twice or thrice daily so I will say it is an effective workaround that has obviated the need to actually find a way of creating a task to stop and restart. Hopefully MS will sort this issue out but I am not holding my breath. The only thing I wonder is - when it does stop and I point it to E:\{xxx}\ , my brain wonders if taking the proffered option of C:\Users\sean\  would also work as well. I am just too chicken to test it.